# When is it safe to call URL.revokeObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, html

If I understand correctly `URL.createObjectURL` creates a URL that represents a file or a blob. Because the URL is just a string the browser has no way to know when you're finished with the resource that URL represents so there's a provided `URL.revokeObjectURL` function.

MDN shows [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  var newImg = document.createElement("img");
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  newImg.onload = function() {
    // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };

  newImg.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(newImg);
});
```

So some questions

1. Would it be safe to change the code to revoke the URL immediately after assigning `newImg.src`?

   ```
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

   canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
     var newImg = document.createElement("img");
     var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

     newImg.src = url;
     // no longer need to read the blob as it's assigned to newImg.src
     URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
     document.body.appendChild(newImg);
   });
   ```

   I'm guessing the answer is "no" because potentially nothing has started on `newImg.src = url;`. It's still just a string at that point and will remain so until the current JavaScript event exits. Or is it?
2. Would it be valid/legal/correct to revoke the URL but still use it knowing it's referenced by other objects?

   ```
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

   canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
     var newImg = document.createElement("img");
     var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

     newImg.onload = function() {
       // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
       URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

       // Use the URL again even though it's revoked
       var newImg2 = new Image():
       newImg2.src = url; 
     };

     newImg.src = url;
     document.body.appendChild(newImg);
   });
   ```

   In this case I'm assigning `newImg2.src = url` even though I've already revoked the URL. The idea being that `newImg` is still referencing the blob URL so it would seem valid to be able to say

   ```
   someImage.src = someOtherImage.src
   ```

   at any time. Is it?

Comment: 1. Likely not, because that URL has to be _parsed into_ an image by the browser, and that takes time. 2. `newImg.src` _is not_ your “old” blob URL any more, it’s just a (data) URL like from any other source. So that the “original” has been revoked (and therefor handed over to garbage collection) doesn’t affect what you are doing here in _any_ way.

Comment: couldn't you just [test](https://jsfiddle.net/kcgwvcs4/) this

Answer (score 10):

Okay, well, following @adeneo's advice I tested this

```js
$('#test').on('change', function(e) {
 var newImg = document.createElement("img");
    var url = URL.createObjectURL( e.target.files[0] )
    console.log(url);
    
    newImg.src = url;
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    document.body.appendChild(newImg);
    console.log(url);
});

$('#test3').on('change', function(e) {
 var newImg = document.createElement("img");
    var url = URL.createObjectURL( e.target.files[0] )
    console.log(url);
    
    newImg.src = url;
    newImg.onload = function() {
     URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
     document.body.appendChild(newImg);
      var i = new Image();
      i.src=  newImg.src;
      document.body.appendChild(i);
      setTimeout(function() {
        var g = new Image();
        g.src = newImg.src;
        document.body.appendChild(g);
      }, 3000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>test revoke before use</p>
<input type="file" id="test"/>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>test use revoke use</p>
<input type="file" id="test3" />
```

At least in Firefox, once `URL.revokeObjectURL` is called the URL can no longer be used, even though other things are accessing it.

So both #1 and #2 in the question fail and, even though in #2 `newImg.src` still has the URL that URL won't work anywhere else once `URL.revokeObjectURL` has been called.

Comment: so basically until we have image that needs to show the image (via src) - we should not call "revoke"?

Comment: I revoked my blob after I set it as an `img` src, everything was fine. I revoked my blob after I set it as a `background-image` css property, everything was not fine! Firefox was used.

Comment: I'd expect imgs to be fine if you use the URL before revoking but not fine if you try to use the URL after revoking.

Answer (score -3):

In React, there is a hook called useEffect, and one of the things that it does, is what action would you like to take right before you're leaving the component(function), and there you release the existing object URL which was previously created by calling URL.createObjectURL().

Releasing an existing object URL using URL.revokeObjectURL:

```js
useEffect(() => () => URL.revokeObjectURL(file as string), [file])

const onChangeFile = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
        setFile(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]))
    }
}
```